# Inputbox BASH inster a Json in a inputbox

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, dialog

How can i request to the user to insert an JSON into a dialog in bash? Im trying with whiptail or dialog, but both have the same problem, only a simple text can be writed

Comment: Please try to give your question a title that makes a bit of sense. Don't try to put every possibly related keyword into it, that's rather what tags are for. Also, review the tags you applied, approximately two of your three are wrong or bad. Further, JSON *is* text, so it's unclear what your problem is or what behaviour you expect. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Are you talking about the `dialog` command? Are you trying to insert a multilne string in a `dialog --inputbox ...` control?

Comment: `dialog` has an `--editbox` widget that is intended for file contents editing. But you can use a "template" json file (possibly empty, or containing only `{}`) and you'll get a "texarea"-like editor: `dialog --editbox /path/to/your/file 20 60`.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu yeah im talking about dialog and a multiline string,! Ill try with editbox